# Is there a way to batch copy port names over to net names

Tags: schematics, altium

version Altium Designer 15.1

#### Scenario

- I have a several pins wired to ports.
- I want to remove the ports and add net names to the corresponding wire
- I want the wire net names to be the same as the port name for now.  I will add to the net name later.

#### Question

How do I go about doing this in the most efficient way possible?  Right now I'm creating each net name, assigning them to a wire and copy/pasting the corresponding port name over to the net name.

Comment: You can also click "allow ports to name nets" (if you can find it) and then you (maybe) don't have to place the net names at all.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bullet point where you say you want to remove the ports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Edit > Smart Paste function.

- Select all your ports,
- copy them (Ctrl+C) then use
- Edit->Smart Paste and
- select "Net Labels" in the dialogue.

Then Altium Designer will paste net labels with the same names for you.
This also works for Power Objects and busses. Take a look at the options in the dialogue or the [documentation for Smart Paste](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/Sch_Dlg-SmartPasteForm((Smart+Paste))_AD).

Comment: To select all your ports, either use a rectangle selection or find similar objects.